# Apache with no apxs

Tags: python-2.7, apache2, mod-wsgi, synology, apxs2

I am running Apache on a Synology 1512+. I would like to do some development using python and have chose to use `mod_wsgi` to serve. I initially installed `ipkg` and used that to instal `mod_wsgi`. Unfortunately, it seems to have installed python 2.5 (and possible another apache) instead of using the currently installed Python 2.7 and the running Apache. I decided to just try to compile my own mod_wsgi, but it appears that I am missing apxs?

The following is the error that I receive. I am at a loss for what to do next. Using `ipkg` or compiling myself are my own two known options. Am I able to just download a compiled version or something?

```
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7

checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking Apache version... ./configure: ./configure.lineno: line 1704: apxs: not found
./configure: ./configure.lineno: line 1704: apxs: not found
./configure: ./configure.lineno: line 1705: apxs: not found
./configure: ./configure.lineno: line 1723: /: Permission denied    
./configure: ./configure.lineno: line 1877: apxs: not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ipkg to install the development package for Apache corresponding to the core Apache package you installed. The development package contains apxs, but more importantly contains the header files for Apache which mod_wsgi will need when it is being compiled. One can work around the lack of apxs, but if you do not have the correct Apache headers files, you cannot do anything.

Comment: What is the easiest way to delete all of these ipkg after they are installed? I would rather not have all of these things floating around.

Comment: Package managers would provide a means to remove packages you installed, so check the documentation for the package manager. Just be aware that you have to be careful about what you remove as a core package may have installed shared libraries or configuration files that are needed as run time. Removing of the Apache development package later should be okay though.

Comment: Hi,

I tryed to do the same and I got the same error. So I downloaded the apache Package with ipkg and tried the `--with-apxs=/opt/sbin/apxs` option but it said it could not find the apxs package ... do you have an idea what I did do wrong ?
Or could you tell me where to get a "apache-dev" version compatible with the linux version on the ds?

Comment: Just btw ... the mod-wsgi package from the ipkg come with python 2.5 and another apache.. which you will have to configure and set up yourself. I did not have the time if it is working ...